# Applying environment variables to JBoss Bootable Jar in OpenShift/Docker?

Tags: docker, jboss, openshift

I have an application that I am testing in Docker as a JBoss bootable jar. The dockerfile adds the jar to the container, and then runs it. I'd like to pass the database credentials as environment variables for testing, and then as secrets in OpenShift. I tried adding the jar and manipulating it prior to running the CMD java -jar myapp.jar, but the path varies from build to build, and my attempt to capture the path doesn't work when I build the image. I also considered injecting the variables after the application is deployed. It worked, but it was a manual process.

Pre-altering the file did not work because as I was unzipping the files, I was unable to set a variable to store the random path.

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi8/openjdk-17-runtime

USER root

ENV envhostname=localhost envusername=myappuser envpassword=myapppassword envSID=myappsid

RUN microdnf install fontconfig &&\
    microdnf install zip-3.0-23.el8.x86_64

USER 185

ADD myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar

RUN unzip myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar
RUN     unzip -n wildfly.zip
RUN     export contentpath=$(find . -name "content" | grep -E 'content.+content')
RUN     unzip $contentpath
RUN     contentpath=${contentpath::-7}
RUN     sed -i "s/envhostname/$envhostname/i" $contentpath/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
RUN     sed -i "s/envusername/$envusername/i" $contentpath/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
RUN     sed -i "s/envpassword/$envpassword/i" $contentpath/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
RUN     sed -i "s/envSID/$envSID/i" $contentpath/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
RUN     zip -f -Ar $contentpath/content $contentpath/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
RUN     zip -f wildfly.zip $contentpath/content
RUN     zip -f myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar wildfly.zip
    
CMD java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar
```

And I don't know how to automatically trigger a shell script to run after the CMD.

There has to be some better way to handle this.

Comment: More details would be required like the deployment definition where the command is used to run the bootable jar or to how the container is invoking the bootable jar.  if requirement is reading environment variables in myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar then you can use secret and load as environment variables.  following link has examples https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: I've added the entirety of my dockerfile. Calling "java -jar myapp-bootable.jar" deploys a jboss server at /tmp/wildfly-bootable-server[bunchanumbers]/, and the war file is stored in /tmp/wildfly.../standalone/data/content/[2digithex]/[38digithex]/content.

I have manually run pre-deployment by removing the series of RUN commands and changing CMD to bash shell and then running the commands to unzip, edit, and zip, and then call java -jar, and I have manually run post-deployment by opening a terminal and running the commands to edit the file on the JBoss server.

Comment: Is there a way to call java -jar in the background so that I can use CMD bash to start the server and then to run a script to edit the file?

Answer (score 0):

Oof. I just needed to think this through more. I solved this by modifying my Dockerfile as such

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi8/openjdk-17-runtime

USER root

ENV envhostname=localhost envusername=myappuser envpassword=mapppw envSID=myapp

RUN microdnf install fontconfig &&\
    microdnf install zip-3.0-23.el8.x86_64

ADD myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar
ADD prepcfg.sh prepcfg.sh

RUN chmod 777 myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar

USER 185

CMD ["./prepcfg.sh"]
```

and creating prepcfg.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

unzip myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar
unzip -n wildfly.zip
export contentpath=$(find . -name "content" | grep -E 'content.+content')
contentpath=${contentpath::-7}
cd $contentpath
unzip content
sed -i "s/envhostname/$envhostname/i" WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
sed -i "s/envusername/$envusername/i" WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
sed -i "s/envpassword/$envpassword/i" WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
sed -i "s/envSID/$envSID/i" WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
zip -f -Ar content WEB-INF/classes/myapp/common/bc4j.xcfg
cd ~
zip wildfly.zip $contentpath/content
zip myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar wildfly.zip
java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootable.jar
```

Because I don't need to worry about running two commands when I can just initialize my JBoss server at the end of the script called in the Dockerfile.